# VSTS: anyone knows when we'll be able to have a CI build using VS 2017?

Tags: continuous-integration, visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines

does anyone know when we'll be able to have a CI build using VS 2017 on the default host agent?

Thanks.

Luis

Comment: What do you mean? You can do that now with both VSTS and TFS 2017?

Comment: Do you mean Hosted Agent? You can track the update of this article https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got an answer on twitter. it seems like it's coming this week https://twitter.com/tfsbuck/status/842471101699637248

Answer (score 1):

On your Visual Studio build task in your build you can set the version of Visual Studio used ti build... Or you can just set "Latest".

[image]

Edit your build, select the Visual studio compile task and look for the Visual Studio Version selector.